# How can we create a button, that runs the function we have given and takes the input given and performs tasks that we have given?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button, inputbox

I'm trying to make a function which takes the time that is received as an input (in the format of 24 hours) and returns the sentence, "Good Morning" if the time is of morning or returns "Good Afternoon" if the time is after 12pm or returns "Good Evening" if it's after 4pm but before 12am.

````
    ```
    <script>
    function greet(when) {
    if (when < 1200) {
    return "Good Morning";
    }
    else {
    return "Good Afternoon";
    }
    </script>
    ```
````

The problem I'm facing is, that I want to make a button that takes the input and performs tasks we have told to perform, but I don't know how because I'm new in JavaScript and not able to solve this even with the help of Google. The code I have in the HTML's form section is

```
    <form>
    <input type = "text" id = "when" value = "What time 
    is it?" />
    <button type = "submit" 
    onclick="Function(greet)">Click me</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this. A form performs a post request(usually) since you don't have a server to handle this request you don't need a form.

```js
function greet() {
  var when = document.getElementById('when').value;

  if (when < 1200) {
    alert( "Good Morning" );
  }
  else {
     alert( "Good Afternoon" );
  }
}
```

```html
<input type = "text" id = "when" value = "" placeholder="What time 
is it?"/>
<button type = "submit" 
onclick="greet()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
function greet() {
    let date = Date.now();
    if (date < yourvalue) {
    return "Good Morning";
    }
    else {
    return "Good Afternoon";
    }
```